# Twig Templates : Include dynamic data when using set

Tags: templating

I'm trying to use [the Encode Email plugin](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/encode-email/docs/getting-started/introductio) to encode email addresses.

The email addresses are dynamic so I need to include the output from the database when I'm using set.

This is their example that doesn't use dynamic info:

```
{% set email = "<a href='mailto:you@example.com'>Your Name</a>" %}
{{ email | rot13 }}
```

And this is what I've tried that doesn't work.

```
{% set email = "<a href='mailto:{{ contactInfo.contactEmail }}'>{{ contactInfo.contactEmail }}</a>" %}
{{ email | rot13 }}
```

Is there a way to include the dynamic variables into the set statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing to remember about Twig... **You never need to nest tags within other tags**. So putting `{{ }}` within `{% %}` is never going to work.

To concatenate a string in Twig, [use the `~` character...](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#expressions)

```
{% set email = "<a href='mailto:" ~ contactInfo.contactEmail ~ "'>" ~ contactInfo.contactEmail ~ "</a>" %}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Never knew about concatenation in Twig so that's great to learn you can do that. Thanks again.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is to use the other [set syntax](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html):

```
{% set email %}
  <a href="mailto:{{ contactInfo.contactEmail }}">{{ contactInfo.contactEmail }}</a>
{% endset %}
```

Sometimes it is easier to read.